# Convert class based to Function based compnent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

Here I'm working on AutoComplete and Auto fill of react.

I'm trying to convert it to react hooks as I have written all of my code is in hooks only.

I've to some level converted it to hooks based as per my understanding. But I'm not able to completely convert it.

### Original code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      item: {
        code: "",
        name: "",
        unit: "",
        rate: ""
      },
      cursor: 0,
      searchItems: []
    };
    this.autocomplete = this.autocomplete.bind(this);
    this.handleKeyup = this.handleKeyup.bind(this);
    this.handleKeydown = this.handleKeydown.bind(this);
    this.handleListKeydown = this.handleListKeydown.bind(this);
    this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  autocomplete(evt) {
    let text = evt.target.value;
    fetch(`https://invoiceitems.herokuapp.com/items?name_like=${text}&_limit=6`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ searchItems: data });
      });
  }

  handleKeyup(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 27) {
      this.setState({ searchItems: [] });
      return false;
    }
  }

  handleKeydown(evt) {
    const { cursor, searchItems } = this.state;
    // arrow up/down button should select next/previous list element
    if (evt.keyCode === 38 && cursor > 0) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        cursor: prevState.cursor - 1
      }));
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 40 && cursor < searchItems.length - 1) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        cursor: prevState.cursor + 1
      }));
    }
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
      let currentItem = searchItems[cursor];
      if (currentItem !== undefined) {
        const { name, code, rate, unit } = currentItem;
        this.setState({ item: { name, code, rate, unit }, searchItems: [] });
      }
    }
    if (evt.keyCode === 8) {
      this.setState({ item: { name: "", code: "", rate: "", unit: "" } });
    }
  }

  selectItem(id) {
    const { searchItems } = this.state;
    let selectedItem = searchItems.find((item) => item.code === id);
    const { code, name, unit, rate } = selectedItem;
    this.setState({ item: { code, name, unit, rate } });
    this.setState({ searchItems: [] });
  }

  handleListKeydown(evt) {
    console.log(evt.keyCode);
  }

  handleChange(evt) {
    this.setState({ item: { [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value } });
  }

  render() {
    const { searchItems, cursor, item, handleChange } = this.state;
    const { code, name, unit, rate } = item;
    return (
      <div className="container mt-3">
        <h1 className="h2 text-center">Autocomplete Example</h1>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="autocomplete">Item Name </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="autocomplete"
            onChange={this.autocomplete}
            onKeyUp={this.handleKeyup}
            onKeyDown={this.handleKeydown}
            value={name}
            className="custom-input form-control"
          />
          {searchItems.length > 0 && (
            <ul className="list-group">
              {searchItems.map((item, idx) => (
                <li
                  className={
                    cursor === idx
                      ? "active list-group-item"
                      : "list-group-item"
                  }
                  key={idx}
                  onClick={() => this.selectItem(item.code)}
                  onKeyDown={(evt) => this.handleListKeydown(evt, item.code)}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Link to original code: https://codepen.io/regexp/details/RwPNaLe

### Using hooks

Here is the code that I tried to convert to hooks.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function FunctionName(props) {
  const [item, setItem] = useState({
    vendorNameData: invoiceDetail[0].invoiceData.vendor,
    vendorAccountData: invoiceDetail[0].invoiceData.vendaAccount,
    vendorAddressData: invoiceDetail[0].invoiceData.vendorAddress
  });
  const [cursor, setCursor] = useState(0);
  const [searchItems, SetSearchItems] = useState([]);

  function AutoComplete(evt) {
    let text = evt.target.value;
    console.log(text);
    fetch(`https://invoiceitems.herokuapp.com/items?name_like=${text}&_limit=6`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        SetSearchItems(data);
      });
  }

  function HandleKeyUp(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 27) {
      SetSearchItems([]);
      return false;
    }
  }

  function HandleKeyDown(evt) {
    // const [cursor, setCursor] = useState();
    // const [searchItems, SetSearchItems] = useState()

    if (evt.keyCode === 38 && cursor > 0) {
      setCursor((cursor) => ({ cursor: cursor + 1 }));
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 40 && cursor < searchItems.length - 1) {
      setCursor((cursor) => ({ cursor: cursor + 1 }));
    }
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
      let currentItem = searchItems[cursor];
      if (currentItem !== undefined) {
        const {
          vendorNameData,
          vendorAccountData,
          vendorAddressData
        } = currentItem;
        setItem({ vendorNameData, vendorAccountData, vendorAddressData });
        SetSearchItems([]);
      }
    }
    if (evt.keyCode === 8) {
      setItem({
        vendorNameData: "",
        vendorAccountData: "",
        vendorAddressData: ""
      });
    }
  }

  function SelectItem(id) {
    const [searchItems, SetSearchItems] = useState();
    let selectedItem = searchItems.find((item) => item.code === id);
    const {
      vendorNameData,
      vendorAccountData,
      vendorAddressData
    } = selectedItem;
    setItem({ vendorNameData, vendorAccountData, vendorAddressData });
    SetSearchItems([]);
  }

  function HandleListKeyDown(evt) {
    console.log(evt.keyCode);
  }

  function HandleChange(evt) {
    setItem({ item: { [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value } });
  }
}
```

It would be really helpful to point me out where I'm lagging. I've tried my best but this is what I could come up with.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've 'traduced' and cleaned up your original component, resulting as follows: (please see notes below)

```
import React, {useState, useCallback} from 'react';

function Input() {
    const [item, setItem] = useState({
        code: '',
        name: '',
        unit: '',
        rate: ''
    });

    const [cursor, setCursor] = useState(0);

    const [searchItems, setSearchItems] = useState([]);

    const autocomplete = useCallback((evt) => {
        const text = evt.target.value;
        fetch(
            `https://invoiceitems.herokuapp.com/items?name_like=${text}&_limit=6`
        )
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setSearchItems(data);
            });
    }, []);

    const handleKeyup = useCallback((evt) => {
        if (evt.keyCode === 27) {
            setSearchItems([]);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }, []);

    const handleKeydown = useCallback(
        (evt) => {
            // arrow up/down button should select next/previous list element
            if (evt.keyCode === 38 && cursor > 0) {
                setCursor((prevCursor) => prevCursor - 1);
            } else if (evt.keyCode === 40 && cursor < searchItems.length - 1) {
                setCursor((prevCursor) => prevCursor + 1);
            }

            if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
                let currentItem = searchItems[cursor];
                if (currentItem !== undefined) {
                    const {code, name, unit, rate} = currentItem;
                    setItem({code, name, unit, rate});
                    setSearchItems([]);
                }
            }

            if (evt.keyCode === 8) {
                setItem({code: '', name: '', unit: '', rate: ''});
            }
        },
        [cursor, searchItems]
    );

    const selectItem = useCallback(
        (id) => {
            let selectedItem = searchItems.find((item) => item.code === id);
            const {code, name, unit, rate} = selectedItem;
            setItem({code, name, unit, rate});
            setSearchItems([]);
        },
        [searchItems]
    );

    const handleListKeydown = useCallback((evt) => {
        console.log(evt.keyCode);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={'container mt-3'}>
            <h1 className={'h2 text-center'}>{'Autocomplete Example'}</h1>
            <div className={'form-group'}>
                <label htmlFor={'autocomplete'}>{'Item Name'}</label>
                <input
                    type={'text'}
                    id={'autocomplete'}
                    onChange={autocomplete}
                    onKeyUp={handleKeyup}
                    onKeyDown={handleKeydown}
                    value={item.name}
                    className={'custom-input form-control'}
                />
                {searchItems.length > 0 && (
                    <ul className={'list-group'}>
                        {searchItems.map((item, idx) => (
                            <li
                                className={
                                    cursor === idx
                                        ? 'active list-group-item'
                                        : 'list-group-item'
                                }
                                key={idx}
                                onClick={() => selectItem(item.code)}
                                onKeyDown={handleListKeydown}>
                                {item.name}
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export {Input};
```

- [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) replaces Class Components State management. It is good practice to split your state into smaller pieces as possible, because new values will completely replace old ones (there is no merging like Class Components `this.setState` does). Using `cursor` as an example, do `const [cursor, setCursor] = useState(0);` to initialize your state (in this case initial state is `0`). Then use `cursor` to use the value and call `setCursor(newValue)` to update it. Each time you update your state you will most likely trigger a re-rendering.
- [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) allows you to only re-declare a function when its dependencies have changed, thus improving performance. Function dependencies are specified in the second argument array. On each render, React will compare the new values with the old ones and will always return the same function when dependencies have not changed.
- The `return` statement replaces your previous `render` method.

Follows a working snippet. Please note that OP original code behavior has not been changed.

```js
const {useState, useCallback, StrictMode} = React;

function Input() {
    const [item, setItem] = useState({
        code: '',
        name: '',
        unit: '',
        rate: ''
    });

    const [cursor, setCursor] = useState(0);

    const [searchItems, setSearchItems] = useState([]);

    const autocomplete = useCallback((evt) => {
        const text = evt.target.value;
        fetch(
            `https://invoiceitems.herokuapp.com/items?name_like=${text}&_limit=6`
        )
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setSearchItems(data);
            });
    }, []);

    const handleKeyup = useCallback((evt) => {
        if (evt.keyCode === 27) {
            setSearchItems([]);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }, []);

    const handleKeydown = useCallback(
        (evt) => {
            // arrow up/down button should select next/previous list element
            if (evt.keyCode === 38 && cursor > 0) {
                setCursor((prevCursor) => prevCursor - 1);
            } else if (evt.keyCode === 40 && cursor < searchItems.length - 1) {
                setCursor((prevCursor) => prevCursor + 1);
            }

            if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
                let currentItem = searchItems[cursor];
                if (currentItem !== undefined) {
                    const {code, name, unit, rate} = currentItem;
                    setItem({code, name, unit, rate});
                    setSearchItems([]);
                }
            }

            if (evt.keyCode === 8) {
                setItem({code: '', name: '', unit: '', rate: ''});
            }
        },
        [cursor, searchItems]
    );

    const selectItem = useCallback(
        (id) => {
            let selectedItem = searchItems.find((item) => item.code === id);
            const {code, name, unit, rate} = selectedItem;
            setItem({code, name, unit, rate});
            setSearchItems([]);
        },
        [searchItems]
    );

    const handleListKeydown = useCallback((evt) => {
        console.log(evt.keyCode);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={'container mt-3'}>
            <h1 className={'h2 text-center'}>{'Autocomplete Example'}</h1>
            <div className={'form-group'}>
                <label htmlFor={'autocomplete'}>{'Item Name'}</label>
                <input
                    type={'text'}
                    id={'autocomplete'}
                    onChange={autocomplete}
                    onKeyUp={handleKeyup}
                    onKeyDown={handleKeydown}
                    value={item.name}
                    className={'custom-input form-control'}
                />
                {searchItems.length > 0 && (
                    <ul className={'list-group'}>
                        {searchItems.map((item, idx) => (
                            <li
                                className={
                                    cursor === idx
                                        ? 'active list-group-item'
                                        : 'list-group-item'
                                }
                                key={idx}
                                onClick={() => selectItem(item.code)}
                                onKeyDown={handleListKeydown}>
                                {item.name}
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <StrictMode>
        <Input />
    </StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.active {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response...keycode and everything is working just fine....but curson is not working as it doesnot shows the clickable icon over the dropdownlist to select....could you please some help with it?

Comment: and also could you tell me where this prevCursor came from...means what exactly is the purpose of this?

Comment: @SangamBasnet `prevCursor` is just a name for the previous cursor state value (number). When you pass a function to the state updater, you receive as argument the latest value for that state. Just like with `this.setState` in Class Components.

Comment: @SangamBasnet I've just updated the snippet with provisional CSS for cursor logic to be visible.